# Application of Tensorflow layer on matrix dimensions and Keras equivalent

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have a Tensorflow code:

```
.
.
leaky_relu(tf.matmul(tf.transpose(out2, perm=[0, 2, 1, 3]), tf.transpose(out2, perm=[0, 2, 3, 1])))
.
.
```

Here, the output of the `tf.matmul` has a shape of `(4, 9, 9)`. Then I feed this to a `leaky_relu` layer.

Now my question is, if I rewrite this using Keras, is the following "translation" accurate?

```
.
.
out2 = Lambda(lambda x: K.dot(K.permute_dimensions(x, (0, 2, 1, 3)), K.permute_dimensions(x, (0, 2, 3, 1))), output_shape=(4,9,9))(out2)
out2 = Flatten()(out2)
out2 = Dense(324, kernel_initializer='glorot_normal', activation='linear')(out2)
out2 = LeakyReLU(alpha=.2)(out2)
out2 = Reshape((4, 9, 9))(out2)
.
.
```

Comment: @josoler Just in case you had any comments on the follow up question . . .

Comment: Not sure what you mean, the leaky ReLU operation is applied individually to each value in the given tensor, so there is no "axis" to it. You receive a tensor with some shape as input and get another tensor with the same shape as output.

Comment: THanks, that's what I'm asking: In a previous question, I was told that in Keras, `Dense` layer is only applied on the last dimension. So I thought that if I want to apply it on all elements, I have to flatten it, apply layer, and reshape it. Now, in the tensorflow code, I don't see these (flatten/reshape), so my question is exactly what you answered: In tensorflow the leaky ReLU is applied on each element, and input and output shapes are equal. So then, would you say that these two codes are equivalent?

Comment: Yes, a dense layer is a matrix multiplication, and so it is performed across some axis. Leaky ReLU is an element-wise operation that is applied to each value in the tensor, whatever the shape. So, given the same input, the result should be the same in both cases.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback!